# Unable to remove directories recursively in ionic capacitor/filesystem

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I’m trying to remove directory from a documents folder, the directory was even created by the application using capacitor filesystem plugin,
when I uninstall the app and install again, I need to delete those previous files, but I’m unable to do this, even after hours of trying.
My code fails silently, doesn’t throw any error / exception. Here’s how I’m trying

```
try {
      await Filesystem.rmdir({
        path: 'lgps_courses',
        directory: Directory.Documents,
        recursive: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Error deleting parent folder: ' + error)
    }
```

I've also enabled permission by adding this to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you to solve your problem. I found this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4656) on capacitor's GitHub, maybe it can help you, it says:

> If you target SDK 30, then android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" will not work on Android 11+ devices.
> Google doesn't allow to programmatically access externally shared files anymore. (Documents and ExternalStorage)

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app

Comment: thanks I have already tried it, but it doesn't seems to be working